# mexCallMATLAB syntax for assigning output

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I've spent a week on the following problem and I can't for the life of me figure it out! I'm going to be as brief as possible with the code and chop out irrelevant lines but it should be clear as to my problem.  For starters, I'm using Matlab in combination with C, which communicates via mex files. Without further ado...

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  static double *U
  plhs[4] = mxCreateNumericArray(2,dims,mxDOUBLE_CLASS,mxREAL);
  U  = (double*)mxGetPr(plhs[4]);

  /* C code which solves for "U" based on a number of other input variables*/
  solve(U,...,...,...)

  /* C code which solves for "U" based on a number of other input variables*/
  derivative(U,...,...,...)
}
```

After execution, everything works fine and I have the value for the derivative of "U". I then wanted to compare solvers so I'm swapping out the "solve(U)" for a Matlab function which I call via "mexCallMATLAB".  Here is where I get lost

(Again I removed irrelevant variables)

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  static double *U
  plhs[4] = mxCreateNumericArray(2,dims,mxDOUBLE_CLASS,mxREAL);
  U  = (double*)mxGetPr(plhs[4]);

  /* Call MATLAB solver */
  mxArray *Uin[8],*Uout[2];
  Uin[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(2,dims,mxSINGLE_CLASS,mxREAL);

  memcpy(mxGetPr(Uin[0]),(some variable),m*n*sizeof(float));
```

yes there are 8 inputs...I just removed for simplicity

```
  mexCallMATLAB(2,Uout,8,Uin,"my_matlab_solver");
```

I then check the results of "Uout" with the following:

```
  mexCallMATLAB(0,NULL,1,&Uout[0],"plot_variable");
```

Everything works out great, but the "C" code that later calls on the variable "U" to find it's derivative does not work.

```
  plhs[4] = Uout[0];

  /* C code which solves for "U" based on a number of other input variables*/
  derivative(U,...,...,...)

}
```

I can not figure out how to assign "Uout[0]" to "U".  I thought by setting plhs[4] = Uout[0] then U would point to the results from "my_matlab_solver" but it does not.  There are no compile errors.

Is there easier way where I can assign the output of "my_matlab_solver" directly to "U" with out having to make a mxArray for the output? This whole MEX thing seems a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: What exactly "does not work" when you calculate the derivative after calling `mexCallMATLAB`? Are there runtime errors or are the results wrong?

Comment: If you just want to compare the output of your C solving algorithm with one in MATLAB, and you already have the C algorithm working, why not do all the comparison stuff straight from MATLAB and forget about calling MATLAB from the MEX?

Comment: Florian: The variable "U" that is passed to the derivative function contains all zeros, as if it's never updated.  I need to assign the output from the mexCallMATLAB function to "U".  The method that I tried apparently does not update "U" and I don't know why.

Comment: Wakjah: The simple answer is that there is an entire code behind my example.  I don't think I'm trying to do something that obscure...I just can't get it to work and was hoping someone could provide a valid solution.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack: in your code, you assigned the output of the solver to `plhs[4]` not `U`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to tell where the problem is without seeing more code. As I mentioned in the comments, I suspect you are assigning the values in the wrong variable...

Here is a toy example to show how to call MATLAB from a MEX-function and manipulate the arrays. Perhaps it would help:

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    // check for proper number of input/output
    if(nrhs != 0 || nlhs > 2) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:nlhs", "Wrong number of arguments.");
    } 

    // call: out1 = rand(5,5); out2 = rand(5,5);
    mxArray *Uin[2], *Uout[2];
    Uin[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(5);
    Uin[1] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(5);
    mexCallMATLAB(1, &Uout[0], 2, Uin, "rand");
    mexCallMATLAB(1, &Uout[1], 2, Uin, "rand");

    // compute: out = out1 + out2; and assign it to output
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(5,5,mxREAL);
    double *x = mxGetPr(Uout[0]);
    double *y = mxGetPr(Uout[1]);
    double *z = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    for(int i=0; i<5*5; ++i) {
        *z = *x + *y;
        ++x; ++y; ++z;
    }

    // free memory
    mxDestroyArray(Uin[0]);
    mxDestroyArray(Uin[1]);
    mxDestroyArray(Uout[0]);
    mxDestroyArray(Uout[1]);
}
```

Comment: For anyone who encounters a similar problem, I have provided a solution to my problem here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/76750-help-mxcallmatlab-output-assignment-to-variable The above solution works as well and I thank you for your help and time!!